# Fatal error in avr-gcc, specifies incorrect MCU

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc, attiny

I am learning to program my ATtiny85 without a bootloader using a MiniPro, and I want to generate a hex file. First I try to compile my file using the `avr-gcc` command, but I get an error that states:

```
Fatal error: unknown MCU: gcc-isr
```

This is the command I use to compile my file

```
avr-gcc -Wall -mmcu=avr25 -Os -DF_CPU=8000000 -c main.c -o main.o
```

And this is the code I'm trying to compile

```c
#define __AVR_ATtiny85__
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0b00001000;
    while (1)
    {
        PORTB = 0b00001000;
        _delay_ms(20);
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
        _delay_ms(20);

        PORTB = 0b00001000;
        _delay_ms(200);
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
        _delay_ms(200);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I am not entirely sure what the error means and why it appears in the first place, since my mcu is explicitly specified as avr25 category, which the attiny85 falls into. The same error is produced if I set the mmcu variable to `attiny85` explicitly

Output of `avr-gcc --version`

```
% avr-gcc --version
avr-gcc (GCC) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I also installed the latest `binutils-avr` and `avr-libc` packages from AUR (2.20 and 2.1.0 respectively)

Comment: What is the version of your avr-gcc? It works for me with 11.2, but avr25 was introduced with 4.2.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue using GCC 5.4.0 on Windows, from the [AVR 8-bit Toolchain version 3.6.2](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/microchip-studio/gcc-compilers), but GCC compiled the object file with no errors.  What exact toolchain are you using and how did you install it?  It's definitely better to use `-mccu=attiny85`, by the way.

Comment: @DavidGrayson how do I check the version of my AVR toolchain? The version of avr-gcc is 11.2.0

Comment: You should edit your question to include the full output of `avr-gcc --version`, the full name of your operating system, and the steps you followed to install the AVR toolchain (i.e. what did you download or what package installation command did you run).

Comment: @DavidGrayson I have added the additional information

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on `avr-gcc (Fedora 11.2.0-1.fc36) 11.2.0`. Neither when compiling your original `main.c` with `-mmcu=avr25` nor with the proper `-mmcu=attiny85` and the `#define __AVR_ATtiny85__` removed from `main.c`. Are you sure your avr-libc is built and installed properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Fatal error: unknown MCU: gcc-isr`

This indicates that you are using an outdated Binutils (`as`) and that the compiler was configured against a Binutils version that is newer than the Binutils you are actually using.

Since v8, `avr-gcc` supports option [`-mgas-isr-prologues`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/AVR-Options.html#index-mgas-isr-prologues), and it will activate the respective part of the assembler by calling it with option [`-mgcc-isr`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.38/as/AVR-Pseudo-Instructions.html#AVR-Pseudo-Instructions).  The feature was introduced with Binutils v2.29.

You can

- Re-configure and build `avr-gcc` against the Binutils version you are preferring to use.  The `configure` script does check whether Binutils support `-mgcc-isr`; and if that is not the case, the respective GCC feature will be disabled.
- Use `avr-gcc` with disabled optimization feature [PR20296](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20296) / [PR21683](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21683), i.e. compile with `-mno-gas-isr-prologues`.

---

Apart from that:

`avr-gcc -mmcu=avr25 ...`

**Always** call avr-gcc with the AVR device you are going to use, in your case `-mmcu=attiny85`.  Also remove that

`#define __AVR_ATtiny85__`

which will be defined in `specs-attiny85` which is part of the installation and the central hub that sets command line options for the sub-processes (compiler proper, assembler, linker).  If you have a broken toolchain or are using wrong command line options, this define will not fix it.